# How to set default value in new contact in salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I'm new in Apex development.
I need to set default value for text field in new contact (or)
I have created new custom data field and mapped to the contact when i create new contact the mapped data will be reflected to the particular field
Without pass the data via URL (ie)

/003/e?retURL=%2F003%2Fo&con10=12346789&con6=qwe

Answer (score 0):

A Before Insert/Before Update Apex Trigger can be used to augment a record before it is committed to the database, however, the end user does not see this value on the new Contact form (as this occurs after they click Save).

You can prepopulate fields on the new Contact Form using the URL params as you described, and then it will show up on the form, however, that is not done via Apex.